# "Sheng" as a male given name

Tags: usage, names

Apparently there are quite a lot of characters that are pronounced as "sheng". (According to Pleco: 生、声、省、升、胜、圣、剩，盛、牲、绳、笙、甥、嵊、眚、乘、昇、晟、渑、㗂，呏，曻、泩、陞、鼪)

Which of these could plausibly be used as a (single character) male given name?

Comment: If you read the name in a novel, sheng 生 is sometimes used as a title meaning "student", so something like "Liu Sheng" might be "student Liu" rather than a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

生、声、[**省**]、升、[**胜**]、圣、剩，[**盛**]、牲、绳、笙、甥、嵊、眚、乘、[**昇**]、晟、渑、㗂，呏，曻、泩、陞、鼪

> [**省**] as in 自省 (introspection) *it is very meaningful as a name, but 省 can also mean province, may cause confusion*

The following are very common single character names:

> [**盛**] as in 強盛 (powerful and prosperous)
>
> [**胜**] as in 胜利 (victory)
>
> [**昇**] as in 高昇 (rise high)
>
> *升 and 陞 also mean rise, but as a name, 昇 is the most standard one*

The following are questionable:

> 牲 as in 牲口 (livestock) - *very bad as a name*
>
> 剩 as in 剩余 (left-over; surplus; remaining) - *not suitable as a name*
>
> 生 as in 生存(alive) 生命(life) - *rare used in name because 生 is also a verb for give birth*
>
> 声 as in 声音(sound) - *not very meaningful as a name*
>
> 圣 as in 神圣(holy) - *too arrogant as a name*
>
> 甥 (nephew) - *not suitable as a name*
>
> 乘 (ride)- *not very meaningful as a name*
>
> 绳 (rope) - *not common as a name*

The following are obscure Chinese characters, not suitable as common names:

> 嵊、晟、渑、㗂，呏，曻、泩、鼪

Comment: `省` in `自省` is pronounced `xing3` rather than `sheng3`